# Codeigniter - How to get records from database where one fields value is more than another?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

In my database I have two columns named 'amount_raised' and 'funding_goal'.

I would like to get all records from my database where the 'amount_raised' is equal to or more than the 'funding_goal'.

I am using Codeigniters active record. This is what I have so far:

```
    function get_recently_successful($limit, $offset){

        $data = '';

        $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
        $this->db->where('published', '1'); 
        $this->db->where('amount_raised >=', 'funding_goal'); 
        $query = $this->db->limit($limit, $offset)->get('projects'); 

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'date' => $row->date,
                'project_title' => $row->project_title,

            );
        }

        return $data;

    }
```

The code above just returns all values in the database. Not how I specified it with where. How can I make it work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
$this->db->where('amount_raised >= funding_goal');
```

Right now you send the value 'funding_goal' through the query, thus making it:
`WHERE amount_raised >= 'funding_goal'`

You want it compare with a column and not a string:
`WHERE amount_raised >= funding_goal`

You can always troubleshoot your query by inserting:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

After the `$query =` row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple condition in array, you can try the below as well:

> $this->db->where(array('status' => 'Active', 'category' => $catId));

You can use another condition as well like this:

> $this->db->where('amount_raised >= funding_goal');

You can use the last_query() to see the sql query as well to understand it.